# How to Automate branch switching task in eclipse/STS?

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, sts

Every sprint, I have to checkout the newly created branch for all my projects. Is there a way I can automate this process in eclipse/STS. The branch name is same for all the projects(FY22Q4S6). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch to the same named branch of multiple Git repositories, **select those repositories** in the ***Git Repositories*** view, **right-click** them and choose ***Switch Repositories to > ...***, which lists all names of branches that exists in all selected repositories.

To avoid selecting the repositories, you could put those repositories in a so-called *Repository Group* using the ***Create a Repositories Group*** command via the view menu (the three dots) or via *Find Action* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>).